# Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 RC Expiration

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service-pack

I have a licenced version of Windows Server 2008 R2.

I installed some time ago the SP1 RC of Windows Server 2008 R2.
No problem until yesterday.

Now, every 2 hours, my computer show me this blue screen and have no choice other than rebooting :
[image: Blue screen]

14 days ago, I knew I had to unninstall the RC of the SP1.
Unfortunately, long before this, I deleted the backup files of the SP1 (forgot it was a RC).

So :

- I can't delete the SP1 RC
- I can't install SP1 RTM (it shows me message I have to unninstall RC version...)

Am I stuck in a dead end ?

Is there any solution other than reinstalling Windows ?

[EDIT] : maybe if someone know where I can download the SP1 RC, I can remove it from my computer...

Comment: Certainly an effective way to get users off of the non-release versions, though a little harsh.  I can't find any official MS documentation on this (all the RC stuff got repointed to the RTM stuff), but the jist of what's out there on other sites: **"The RC will expire on November 30, 2011. You will be reminded beginning August 30, 2011"**. That's a heck of a reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft does not support upgrading RC to RTM. So your only supported method is to reinstall.

That being said, if you'd like to do an unsupported upgrade you should be able to boot off the RTM install disc and choose the upgrade option. Results may vary. Backup your data first. Don't blame anybody except yourself if it doesn't work. Don't expect a stable system afterwords. Basically, you probably should just reinstall.

Comment: Argh.. No other solution ? Maybe I can uninstall RC if I have the SP1 RC installation files ? But where can I download it ?

Comment: I ended up making the upgrade with the Server 2008 R2 + SP1 Install ISO. Seems to work :)